# I get NetworkOnMainThreadException eaven when I make request from another thread

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I understand the point of the android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException that targets HoneyComb devices but the following code throws the same exception:

```
class MakeRequest extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
            DefaultHttpClient cli = new DefaultHttpClient();
            try {
                String url = params[0].replace(" ", "%20");
                HttpResponse resp = cli.execute(new HttpGet(url));
                BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resp.getEntity().getContent()));
                String tmp = "",rezultat = "";
                setResult("");

                while ((tmp = read.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    rezultat = rezultat + tmp;
                }
                setResult(rezultat);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                setResult("");
                return null;
            }
            return null;
        }
//Sample call
HttpRequester cc = new HttpRequester();
MakeRequest test = cc.new MakeRequest();
test.doInBackground(url);
```

Comment: try
MakeRequest test = cc.new MakeRequest();
test.execute(url);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```
new MakeRequest().execute(url);
```